# How do I count a Date Column based on another Date Column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, distinct

What I'm trying to achieve is to count the login attempts of a user based on  the LoginAttempts value and on the LastLoginDate. For example, I need to query the LastLoginDate within 30 days with 2 Loginattempts.

[image: sampledb]

result should be:
[image: Output]

What I have is this..I created temp table to pull the information and and it doesn't seem to be counting correctly. Here's where I'm stuck..Any help would be appreciated!!

[image: sample database]

Comment: What results are you getting instead?

Comment: I'm confused about your data model. To me, it looks like first 4 columns are from a `User` table and last column is from a related `Login`(?) table, with a join between them, but your query just shows a `User` table and no `LoginAttempts` column. Or is that the `LoginDateUTC` column? But individual log records of logins wouldn't be in the main `User` table, so I'm confused.

Comment: Your example shows 4 `LoginAttempts` for `JON`, so why do you expect a count of `2`? Or did you mean to only count the *attempts* within 30 days? If so, don't you think the `WHERE` clause should be `LoginDateUTC >= ...`, not `LastLoginDateUTC >= ...`?

Comment: I meant to count the attempts within 30 days. I just didn't put the whole FROM but yes I'm pulling the data from different tables.

Comment: @cat4081 So change `WHERE` clause to limit the "attempt" date, not the "last" date, as I suggested in previous comment.

Comment: @Andreas you're right. the lastlogin is already in the loginattempts so let me try this. thanks!

Comment: Just a suggestion:  please type your code instead of using an image.

Comment: You should show your whole query (as text) and tell us how its result differers from the desired result shown.

Answer (score 2):

Your GROUP BY is incorrect.  It includes LastLoginDateUTC.  Consequently, you're counting logins per date, not logins per 30 days.

Drop LastLoginDateUTC from your GROUP BY, and change the SELECT clause to use `max(LastLoginDateUTC) as LastLoginDateUTC`.  That should give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your request completely, but here's something outside the box.  Good luck!:

```
   select FirstName, StudentID, UserName, LastLoginDate, LoginAttempts,
    RowNumber = row_number() over(partition by StudentID order by StudentID, LoginAttempts)
    into #temp1
    from user
    where cast(LastLoginDate as date) >= getdate()- 30
    --should return all rows of data for past 30 days. 
    --should also rank each loginAttempt by student 

    select * from #temp1
    where RowNumber >= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This not an answer... more a suggestion.

As I see it you have Students and you need to audit login attempts.
This for me is a one to many relation.
So I would keep the Student table, stripped off from any login related data.
This would simplify your `Student` table, keep less rows and save storage space for not using the same data (name, username, etc) over and over again.
That data would be in a `StudentLoginAttempts`, something like:

```
    Create Table StudentLoginAttempts (
        Id int not null identity(1,1),
        StudentId int not null,
        LoginDate datetime not null,
        Successful bit not null,

        Constraint PK_StudentLoginAttempts Primary Key Clustered (Id),
        Constraint FK_StudentLoginAttempts_Student Foreign Key (StudentId) References Student(StudentId)
    )
    go

    Create Index IX_StudentLoginAttempts_StudentId On StudentLoginAttempts(StudentId)
    go

    Create Index IX_StudentLoginAttempts_LoginDate On StudentLoginAttempts(LoginDate)
    go
```

So things could be more clear and you can have more info.
Think the example bellow:

```
Create Table #Student (
    StudentId int not null identity(1,1),
    Username varchar(50) not null,
    FirstName varchar(50) not null
)

Create Table #StudentLoginAttempts (
    Id int not null identity(1,1),
    StudentId int not null,
    LoginDate datetime not null,
    Successful bit not null
)

insert into #Student values
( 'Student001', 'JON' ),
( 'Student002', 'STEVE' )

insert into #StudentLoginAttempts values
( 1, '2016-01-01 09:12', 0 ),
( 1, '2016-02-01 09:12', 0 ),
( 1, '2016-03-01 09:12', 1 ),
( 2, '2016-03-02 10:12', 0 ),
( 2, '2016-04-02 10:12', 1 ),
( 2, '2016-05-02 10:12', 0 )

;with TotalAttemptsCte as (
    select StudentId, TotalLoginAttempts = count(*) from #StudentLoginAttempts group by StudentId
),
FailedCte as (
    select StudentId, FailedLogins = count(*) from #StudentLoginAttempts where ( Successful = 0 ) group by StudentId
),
SuccessfulCte as (
    select StudentId, SuccessfulLogins = count(*) from #StudentLoginAttempts where ( Successful = 1 ) group by StudentId
),
LastSuccessFulDateCte as (
    select StudentId, max(LoginDate) as LastSuccessfulLoginDate
    from
        #StudentLoginAttempts
    where
        ( Successful = 1 ) 
    group by StudentId
)
select
    a.*, b.TotalLoginAttempts, c.FailedLogins, d.SuccessfulLogins, e.LastSuccessfulLoginDate
from
    #Student a
    left join TotalAttemptsCte b       on ( a.StudentId = b.StudentId )
    left join FailedCte c              on ( a.StudentId = c.StudentId )
    left join SuccessfulCte d          on ( a.StudentId = d.StudentId )
    left join LastSuccessFulDateCte e  on ( a.StudentId = e.StudentId )

Drop Table #StudentLoginAttempts
Drop Table #Student
```

You could also create a view based on the query for more easy access.

I remind you that this is just a suggestion, how I would do it.